# Determine the point on the plane $4x-2y+z=1$ that is closest to the point $(-2, -1, 5)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Determine the point on the plane $4x-2y+z=1$ that is closest to the point $(-2, -1, 5)$. This question is from Pauls's Online Math Notes. He starts by defining a distance function:

$z = 1 - 4x + 2y$

$d(x, y) = \sqrt{(x + 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 + (-4 -4x + 2y)^2}$

However, at this point, to make the calculus simpler he finds the partial derivatives of $d^2$ instead of $d$. Why does this give you the same answer?

Comment: Because $t\to t^2$ is increasing in $[0,+\infty)$

Comment: Minimizing $d$ is equivalent to minimizing $d^2$. (Note that $d\ge 0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $$d(x,y)=\sqrt {f(x,y)}$$ for some positive function $f(x,y)$ then the minima of d will correspond to the minima of f.  So, if $f(x,y)$ is differentiable, it makes sense to search for solutions of $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$ where $f=d^2$ rather than calculating partial derivatives of $d$.

In any case, $$ \frac{\partial d}{\partial x} = 0$$ is the same as $$\frac {1}{2} \frac {1}{\sqrt {f(x,y)}} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0 $$ by applying the chain rule which requires $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$$ which is where we started. (Similar conclusion for derivative with respect to $y$)

Answer (score -1):

Here is  a simple solution using tools from middle school for the computation:

Denote $x,y,z$ the coordinates of the orthogonal projection of the point $(-2,-1,5)$
 It satisfies the equations of  proportionality:
$$\frac{x+2}4=\frac{y+1}{-2}=\frac{z-5}1$$
This common ratio is also equal to 
$$\frac{4(x+2)-2(y+1)+1(z-5)}{4^2+(-2)^2+1^2}=\frac{(4x-2y+z)+1}{21}=\frac{2}{21}$$
whence the solution
\begin{cases}
x=-2+\dfrac 8{21}=-\dfrac{34}{21},\\[1ex]
y=-1-\dfrac 4{21}=-\dfrac{25}{21}, \\[1ex]
z= 5+\dfrac 2{21}=\dfrac{105}{21}.
\end{cases}
With these elements, the distance squared is
$$d^2=(x+2)^2+(y+1)^2+(z-5)^2=\frac{8^2+(-4)^2+2^2}{21^2}=\frac{84}{21^2}=\frac{4}{21}$$
and finally $\;d=\dfrac 2{\sqrt{21}}.$

As to your exact question, the differential of $d^2$ is $2d D(d)$, hence the critical values are obtained at the same points, and as $d>0$, $d^2$ and $d$ both increase or both decrease.

Comment: Downvoted because you have answered the question in the title and not answered the partial derivative question that the questioner is actually asking for help with!

Comment: I think  it is more instructive to show how some problems can be solved with very elementary tools.

Comment: I think it is better to answer the particular concern of the questioner.  Maybe he already knows the geometric method and wants to understand the techniques of calculus that can be generalised to solving problems which the elementary tools won't manage.

Comment: That's why I've added  a sketch for his particular question. But I also of the people who might usefule  to see how simple methods sometimes yield efficient solutions.